# Drag and drop functionality not working properly in selenium webdriver for chrome browser

Tags: java, selenium

I have written below code to drag an element and add it in workspace. There is no error in console window however drap drop is not performed on chrome browser.

```
WebElement dragElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sidebar-wrapper']/div/div/nginclude/div[2]/accordion/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]"));
Thread.sleep(4000);
System.out.println("Element Selected to Drag");
WebElement dropElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='workspace']/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/span"));
Thread.sleep(4000);

act.clickAndHold(dragElement).moveToElement(dropElement).release().build().perform();
```

I have tried multiple times but not able to succeed. Please provide your inputs

Comment: try using `DragAndDrop` method from `Actions` class

Comment: Is this HTML 5 drag and drop?

Answer (score 0):

You can try give the location of the element

```
act.clickAndHold(dragElement).perform();
act.moveToElement(dropElement, dropElement.getLocation().getX(), dropElement.getLocation().getY()).perform();
act.release(dropElement).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another method provided in the Selenium documentation here: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#drag-and-drop.

```
WebElement dragElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sidebar-wrapper']/div/div/nginclude/div[2]/accordion/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]"));

WebElement dropElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='workspace']/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/span"));

(new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(dragElement, dropElement).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for drag and drop but I suggest you to optimize your xpath. It might be the real problem for you.

```
WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sidebar-wrapper']/div/div/nginclude/div[2]/accordion/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]"));
Thread.sleep(4000);
System.out.println("Element Selected to Drag");
WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='workspace']/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/span"));
Thread.sleep(4000);
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action mouseOverHome = builder.dragAndDrop(source, target).build();
mouseOverHome.perform();
```

Comment: Hi all thanks for the reply. However above mentioned solutions are not working still there is no error at console

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in Firefox and resolved it by adding an extra movement instruction in front of the moveToElement() instruction, like this:

```
private void dragAndDrop(WebElement element, WebElement target) {
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.clickAndHold(element);
    builder.moveByOffset(20,20);  // THIS was the critical part for me
    builder.moveToElement(target);
    builder.release();
    builder.perform();
}
```